# Can I create a shortcut for a C "Source file" in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse

We can use alt+shift+N to create a new project, but I can't find any shortcut for creating a C source file. Is there a way to create one in case it doesn't exist? of course I can use the menu key, and then use arrow keys to find the C source file option, but it would be cool to know about creating this type of shortcuts, which I don't.

Answer (score 1):

I found it... In Window > preferences > General > Keys > (scroll down...a lot, and there it is) New C project . In binding box, there's also a little lower called new Source file.